# SharedPreferences not saved if battery is taken out while in application or phone is shutdown unexpectly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

My sharedpreferences doesn't get saved for example, a checkbox that is checked if my phone battery is taken out suddenly all of a sudden. Any idea how to get around this problem?

Comment: Upload your code as well for better view..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No events are called when the battery is pulled or there is an unexpected shutdown. The only way to get around this would be to save the preferences every time you change a preference.

For example, your [`CheckBox`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html):

```
CheckBox myCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox);
myCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = <your prefs>;
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        // Store value of "isChecked" into "editor"
        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

You will have to make similar changes for all other preference settings.